# Toggling on and off 220V power

Tags: timer, 555

I have a 9V 555 timer circuit and I want to use it to automatically turn on and off a 220V water pump. What can I use to connect the timer and the pump? Is there like a transformer or something?

Comment: How often? Current rating of the pump? More details needed...

Comment: I already have the timer set. All I need is a relay but thanks for asking anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a **[relay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay)**

Here you have got one that can be set on and off with 5V: [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_sacat=0&_nkw=relay%205v&_frs=1)

Comment: That is a guess at best.

Comment: that is one answer

Answer (score 2):

A 555 doesn't keep any meaningful time. If accuracy is important, and you want some more complex logic than toggling on and off every x seconds, then I'd recommend a Real-Time-Clock (such as the [DS3231](http://www.maximintegrated.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/4627), which has alarm features) that's connected to a basic microcontroller like a PIC12F. Component tolerances for really long periods may be an issue; I'm guessing the pump won't be toggled very often.

From there, you need to use the output to switch mains. **Using your own homebrew circuits to switch mains is a potentially deadly endeavor** if you are not completely confident in what you are doing. Stop now if you aren't and buy [something like this](http://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/noma-timer-with-two-on-off-settings-0528808p.html#.Uwvqz4UwBrs) instead. Otherwise, solid state relays are readily available to switch high voltage mains from low voltage DC sources like a microcontroller and provide isolation. [This one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10636) from Sharp does up to 8A at 400VAC. You need to find one that fits your specifications.

Comment: Q:555;A:PIC ... Olin, is that you? :-)